# PostgreSQL partition pruning problem

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

Let us suppose that I have a table `d_day` containing two columns, `id_day`, and `date`, and a table `fact` that contains two columns, `id_day` and `fact`. My table `fact` is partitioned across `id_day`.

The request

```sql
SELECT * FROM fact
WHERE "ID_DAY" between <ID_A> and <ID_B>
```

is pruning partitions properly, and is almost instant but

```sql
SELECT * FROM fact
INNER JOIN d_dat USING (id_day)
WHERE date between <DATE_A> and <DATE_B>
```

is not. I have a UNIQUE constraint over `date` in my `d_day` column. So, I have a 1:1 relationship between the two columns.

On a broader level, I do not understand how the query planner deals with this demand.

Even something like :

```sql
SELECT * FROM fact
WHERE id_day IN (
   SELECT DISTINCT(id_day) WHERE date BETWEEN <DATE_A> and <DATE_B>
)
```

is slow.

Here is a practical example when filtering on DATEJ:

```sql
set enable_partitionwise_join = true; set enable_partitionwise_aggregate = true;
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, FORMAT JSON)(
select * from "F_TDOJ_HIST_2" fth
inner join "D_TRAIN" dt using ("ID_TRAIN")
inner join "DL_CAPTURE_DATE" dj using ("ID_JOUR", "JX")
where "JX" = -72 
and "ID_ENTNAT" between 4000 and 4999
and "DATEJ" = '2023-12-08'::date);
```

([Explain analyze](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/9737g20ff977abb2))

And here is the example when filtering on ID_JOUR

```sql
set enable_partitionwise_join = true; set enable_partitionwise_aggregate = true;
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, FORMAT JSON)(
select * from "F_TDOJ_HIST_2" fth
inner join "D_TRAIN" dt using ("ID_TRAIN")
inner join "DL_CAPTURE_DATE" dj using ("ID_JOUR", "JX")
where "JX" = -72 
and "ID_ENTNAT" between 4000 and 4999
and "ID_JOUR" = 4756);
```

([Explain analyze](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/4e3ae5cga5g2a124))

Also, when I play the request using DATEJ on a copy of my database, partitioned across a different ID_JOUR span (30 ID_JOUR in a partition vs 3 ID_JOUR) now, I get this plan, which is **much faster**, so I know doing something is possible. I just do not understand why it is now slower, what to change, and why :

```sql
set enable_partitionwise_join = true; set enable_partitionwise_aggregate = true;
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, FORMAT JSON)(
select * from "F_TDOJ_HIST_2" fth
inner join "D_TRAIN" dt using ("ID_TRAIN")
inner join "DL_CAPTURE_DATE" dj using ("ID_JOUR", "JX")
where "JX" = -72 
and "ID_ENTNAT" between 4000 and 4999
and "DATEJ" = '2023-12-08'::date);
```

([Explain analyze](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/gdbbdde66358514h))

Comment: Do yourself a favor, and change all those object names to lower case.

Comment: And remove quoted identifiers!

Comment: I know this is the usual standardization, but I am undergoing a legacy system. But still, I will change it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The decision which partitions must be scanned is either made during query planning or when the query starts executing. But PostgreSQL cannot know at that time what `id_day` values belong to the `d_day` rows where `date` satisfies the condition. So it cannot exclude any partition.

Comment: You confirm that there is absolutely no way to filter on "DATE" through some reindexing of my table ? I have a lot of code to change if I must change all my filters from "DATE" to "ID_DAY".

Comment: Can you think of a theoretical way how this could work? I cannot, short of executing a query on `d_day` first and querying `fact` second, with a list of `id_day`.

Comment: I have a 1:1 relationship between `d_day` and `id_day` in my table `day` (1 <--> 01/01/2010, 2 <--> 02/01/2010, ...), so it should be possible to deduce it. Still, I also tried a `select from where id_day in (select distinct id_day from day where d_day = ...)` and it was just as slow

Comment: Yes, that won't help either. You won't get partition pruning that way.

Comment: But why doesn't it work ?

Comment: Because PostgreSQL cannot possibly deduce that. PostgreSQL would have to first execute the query on `d_dat` to completion, only then it could start executing a query on `fact`, so that it can prune partitions. That's not how the executor works. If you want two queries to run one after the other, you have to do it yourself.

Comment: I tried to illustrate my problem with a practical example. Looking at links like this : https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/2bc1899e624f66e4ca90978540d4e4eeecfe47c6.camel%40cybertec.at and this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61111395/can-postgresql-12-do-partition-pruning-at-execution-time-with-subquery-returning I wonder if a solution to my problem might be found somehow.

Comment: The solution is to run two different queries.

Comment: I would need 1. to change a lot of queries in my ingestion code 2. My users would also need to query on "ID_JOUR" which is very impractical. As I edited in my question, I have a second dev base where my request works in a reasonable time. If I could find a way to understand why it works on my second env and not my first, i would be able to replicate this behavior, which would minimize the amount of code needed, for users and for me.